# Is there an XML tag that is equivalent to `ListView.addHeaderView'?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is there an XML tag which I can use in a layout file that is equivalent to [`ListView.addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)?

Comment: I think it's not exist in original list view. One possible solution is extend `ListView` and create custom attribute to set header view.

Comment: @Yul Can I create custom attributes which can be used in an XML layout file? I'll have to look into that further...

Comment: [**Here**](http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/) buddy

Comment: @Yul Cool, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wrote a simple `ListView` like your requirement.

1. Declare custom attribute in `attrs.xml` in `value` folder:

   ```
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="HeaderListViewFromXML"> 
           <attr name="headerView" format="reference"/>
       </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Create `HeaderListViewFromXML` class extended `ListView`

   ```
   public class HeaderListViewFromXML extends ListView {
       private int headerId;

       public HeaderListViewFromXML(Context context) {
           this(context, null);
       }

       public HeaderListViewFromXML(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           this(context, attrs, 0);
       }

       public HeaderListViewFromXML(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
           TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.HeaderListViewFromXML, defStyle, defStyle);

           try {
               headerId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.HeaderListViewFromXML_headerView, View.NO_ID);
               if (headerId != View.NO_ID) {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   View header = inflater.inflate(headerId, null);
                   addHeaderView(header);
               }
           } finally {
               a.recycle();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Declare custom `HeaderListViewFromXML` in `layout.xml`

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <com.example.rewidget.HeaderListViewFromXML
               android:id="@+id/listWithHeader"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="150dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               // custom attribute. Point to layout in header1.xml
               app:headerView="@layout/header1" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
4. In Activity, use like normal `ListView`

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listWithHeader);

           String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2" };
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

           list.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   }
   ```